# How to loop through local Storage and print results in cells

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (var r = 0; r < localStorage.length; r += 1) {
    var row = table.insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c < 9; c += 1) {
      var cell = r.insertCell(c);
      for (x in localStorage) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x));
        for (i in obj) {
          cell.innerHTML = obj[i];
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

I'm trying to loop through the objects (JSON.stringified) i have stored in my local storage and then print the values in the cells generated each object takes a row and prints the values into cells.
This code only prints the last value of the first object although when i ran it in the console it printed all the values of all the objects. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var r=0;
      var c=0;
      for (x in localStorage) {
        var row = table.insertRow(r);
        var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x));
        for (i in obj) {
          var cell = r.insertCell(c);
          cell.innerHTML = obj[i];
          c++;
        }
        r++;
        c=0;
      }
```

See Edit above...

Comment: Unfortunately not, it now writes the values of all the objects in all of the cells

Comment: the current program is doing:
create row -->
create table cell -->
Add all data to table cell -->
does each local storage need to add to a table cell??
so x is the row and i is the table cell?

Comment: It worked thank you so much man, there was just a little mistake var cell = r.insertCell(c); should've been var cell = row.insertCell(c); thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Json String : { "Name": "Mr. XYZ", "Phone": "9876543210" }

```
    var obj = [];
    obj.push({ "Name": "Mr. XYZ", "Phone": "9876543210" });
    obj.push({ "Name": "Mr. ABC", "Phone": "0123456789" });
    localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageVariableName, JSON.stringify(obj));

    var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageVariableName));
    var flag = 0;

    jQuery.each(item, function (index, value) {
        cell.innerHTML = value.Name + '-' + value.Phone;
    });
```